# has_many, through associations in Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm still trying to grok how to deal with creating/updating `has_many, through:` associations in [Ecto](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.html). I've re-read [José's](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/) post on associations as well as [the docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_many/3), but I'm still struggling.

What I have is this:

**web/models/dish.ex**

```
defmodule Mp.Dish do
  use Mp.Web, :model

  schema "dishes" do
    # ...
    has_many :dish_dietary_prefs, Mp.DishDietaryPref, on_delete: :delete_all,
      on_replace: :delete
    has_many :dietary_prefs, through: [:dish_dietary_prefs, :dietary_pref]
  end

  # ...
end
```

**web/models/dietary_pref.ex**

```
defmodule Mp.DietaryPref do
  use Mp.Web, :model

  schema "dietary_prefs" do
    # ...
    has_many :dish_dietary_prefs, Mp.DishDietaryPref, on_delete: :delete_all,
      on_replace: :delete
    has_many :dishes, through: [:dish_dietary_prefs, :dish]
  end

  # ...
end
```

**web/models/dish_dietary_pref.ex**

```
defmodule Mp.DishDietaryPref do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "dish_dietary_prefs" do
    belongs_to :dish, Mp.Dish
    belongs_to :dietary_pref, Mp.DietaryPref
  end
end
```

I have a JSON endpoint that receives parameters for a `Dish`, inside which I have a key called `dietary_prefs` that is passed as a comma-delimited string, so, for example:

```
[info] POST /api/vendors/4/dishes
[debug] Processing by Mp.Api.DishController.create/2
  Parameters: %{"dish" => %{"dietary_prefs" => "2,1"}, "vendor_id" => "4"}
```

(With additional parameters for `"dish"` removed for this SO post.)

---

How do I handle this in my controller? Specifically, I want this behavior:

1. For `POST` requests (create actions), create the necessary records in `dish_dietary_prefs` to associate this new `Dish` with the given `DietaryPref`s. The comma-delimited string are `id`s for `DietaryPref` records.
2. For `PUT/PATCH` requests (updates), create/destroy the necessary records in `dish_dietary_prefs` to update the associations (users can re-assign dishes to different dietary prefs).
3. For `DELETE` requests, destroy `dish_dietary_prefs`. I think this case is already handled with the `on_delete` configuration in the models.

I already have the logic in my controller to create/update dishes for a given vendor (which is just a simple `has_many/belongs_to` relationship), but I still can't figure out how to create/update/destroy these associations for a given dish.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

If I will ["need to receive the IDs and manually build the intermediate association for each"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33136129/32154) `DietaryPref` I am associating to the `Dish`, could I get an example of how I would do that to the above specification in my controller?

---

***UPDATE***: Just seeing that Ecto 2.0.0-beta.1 is out, and that is [supports `many_to_many`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/blob/v2.0.0-beta.0/CHANGELOG.md#many-to-many), which looks like it would be a solution to my problem. Anyone have an example of using it in action, like I've described above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to the inimitable Jedi-Master José Valim himself, I have got this figured out (in Ecto `2.0.0-beta.1`):

Here's my final controller:

```
def create(conn, %{"dish" => dish_params }, vendor) do
  dietary_prefs = get_dietary_pref_changeset(dish_params["dietary_prefs"])

  changeset = vendor
  |> build_assoc(:dishes)
  |> Repo.preload(:dietary_prefs)
  |> Dish.changeset(dish_params)
  |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:dietary_prefs, dietary_prefs)

  case Repo.insert(changeset) do
    {:ok, dish} ->
      conn
      |> put_status(:created)
      |> render("show.json", dish: dish)
    {:error, changeset} ->
      conn
      |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
      |> render(ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
  end
end

def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "dish" => dish_params}, vendor) do
  dish = Repo.get!(vendor_dishes(vendor), id)
  dietary_prefs = get_dietary_pref_changeset(dish_params["dietary_prefs"])

  changeset = dish
  |> Repo.preload(:dietary_prefs)
  |> Dish.changeset(dish_params)
  |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:dietary_prefs, dietary_prefs)

  case Repo.update(changeset) do
    { :ok, dish } ->
      render(conn, "show.json", dish: dish)
    { :error, changeset } ->
      conn
      |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
      |> render(ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
  end
end

defp vendor_dishes(vendor) do
  assoc(vendor, :dishes)
end

defp parse_dietary_pref_ids(ids) do
  ids
  |> String.split(",")
  |> Enum.map(fn(x) -> Integer.parse(x) |> Kernel.elem(0) end)
end

defp get_dietary_prefs_with_ids(ids) do
  from(dp in DietaryPref, where: dp.id in ^ids) |> Repo.all
end

defp get_dietary_pref_changeset(param) do
  param
  |> parse_dietary_pref_ids
  |> get_dietary_prefs_with_ids
  |> Enum.map(&Ecto.Changeset.change/1)
end
```

---

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-ecto/3cAi6nrsawk

Comment: Note that you also must use `many_to_many` (instead of `has_many X, through: Y`) to get the `put_assoc/3` to function properly. See the Google groups link for the listing that shows this.